# Minimal context-free grammar for a regular language

Tags: automata-theory, context-free-languages

Are there any algorithms for solving exactly the following question?
Given a regular language L, represented as a finite automaton say, what is a CFG with minimal number of nonterminals that generates the language L?

Answer (score 6):

Note that a CFG with $n$ non-terminals can generate a language consisting of a single (highly repetitive) word of length $2^n$, something that only a FSA with $2^n$ states will recognize. Hence in some case your minimal CFG will be much smaller than any FSA for $L$.

Actually, one can get much bigger reduction "factors". Take a deterministic Turing machine $M$ that happens to halt. One can define a CFG $G_M$ that recognizes exactly all words that are not (encodings of) the single run of $M$. This is a language $L$ consisting of all words except the single run, hence a regular language. The size of $G_M$ is polynomial in the size of $M$ while the size of a FSA for $L$ can be enormous (i.e., the single run can be very long, think [Busy Beaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver)). Thus a regular language that requires an enormous FSA can be represented by a tiny grammar.

Your question evokes some notion of *compression of regular languages*. Indeed, the most popular schemes for compressing long words can be seen as some kind of CFGs, 
see J. A. Storer and T. G. Szymanski,
[*Data compression via textual substitution*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/322344.322346).

Comment: Yes it is reduces to the minimal/smallest grammar problem when L is finite. But I don't know if any work has been done on this when it is infinite.